# Click counter keeps resetting to 0

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, counter

This program is supposed to count mouse clicks but it only counts the first one. The code is nothing complicated but I don't get why it only counts the first click.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class swing {
    private JLabel label;

    public swing() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("exemple");
        frame.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("clic clic");
        button.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
        label = new JLabel("0");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.add(button);
        pane.add(label);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane,
        BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.show();
    }
    private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int count = 0;
            count++;
            label.setText("Number of Mouse Clicks = "+ count);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new swing();
    }
}
```

Comment: You always set the "count" back to 0.

Comment: Move your `count =0` outside the `actionPerformed` method but inside the listener class.

Comment: @WJS thank you so much! It worked. You can put the comment as an answer if you want and I'll mark it as a solution.

Comment: Nah.  Don't worry about it.  Besides, @camickr beat me by a few seconds. LoL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to user WJS who has commented with an answer, I had to simply Move count =0 outside the actionPerformed method but inside the listener class.

Answer (score -1):

on every click you are setting the `counter` again to zero and then showing the incremented value and after each click value of `counter` is reset to zero.

you need to move the count outside of `actionPerformed`

```
int count = 0;
private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        count++;
        label.setText("Number of Mouse Clicks = " + count);

    }
}
```